# UnsatisfiedRequirementsError: Node on app engine flex environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy app engine node service on the flex environment.
Below is my configuration in `app.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs8
env: flex

#to name a service use below syntax
service: exampleNodeApp

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: "dev"
  PORT: 3000

skip_files: 
  .env

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

The config is going to use the node8 image. My `package.json` is as below

```
{
  "name": "expressapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node ./bin/www",
   },
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "~4.16.3",
   }
}
```

I have tried specifying the engine also like

```
{
   "node": "~8.*"
}
```

And to see the debug logs i used

```
gcloud app deploy --version default1 --verbosity=debug
```

the error which i get is as below. Not able to resolve even after trying everything. My app runs fine on the local. Please help!

--update-- the error log

```
UnsatisfiedRequirementsError: Your application does not satisfy all of  the requirements for a runtime of type [nodejs8].  Please correct the errors and try again.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [nodejs8].  Please correct the errors and try again.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Somewhat wrongly defined (not explicitly) in the google docs.

the `runtime: nodejs8` is only available for the standard environment. But for the flex env `env: flex` only nodejs can be given as the param. The gcloud run-time builder does not have anything like nodejs8.

Still trying to figure out whats the version of node given `runtime: nodejs`.

will update soon.

For further reference here is how I found the solution 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/651

Comment: its node8 as a default version. Will be updated by google soon

Comment: i tried runtime: nodejs10 and removed env: flex ,,, now its working